How to configure strongSwan on Linux Debian to use Built-In Windows client?
My goal is just to have Linux-based VPN server to which I could connect with build-in Windows client without installing third-party client software on Windows.
I am looking at the strongSwan Configuration for Windows Machine Certificates, but is seems to be a final configuration step.
Am I correct that I should pass all configuration steps like

Configuration Quickstart
Certificates Quickstart
etc.

in order to get it working? Isn't there some way of "easy setup", "default setup", "wizard", etc.?
As I see for the moment, I would have to setup dozens of parameters and learn a lot of stuff before I will be able to launch a simple VPN server for Windows client.
What would be the recommended way for a newcomer to get it working easy and fast?

ipsec is complex. There's a lot to configure. It's probably faster to get started using e.g. wireguard...

@vidarlo, thank you for the hint. The wireguard's guide looks more straightforward and user-friendly. The only question on table is if it allows to configure linux server in a way windows user could use the built-in VPN client. I can't find this part in the manuals. Have you heard of such experience? I am not sure linux server part will provide the necessary protocols.

IPSec is well supported by strongswan, and I see no reason the builtin windows IPSEC functionality won't play well with strongswan.

@vidarlo, it works with Windows. My question was about wireguard which you have recommended. Would it work with Windows build-in VPN and provided protocols? I can't see this kind of details in the wireguard's guide, that's why I am curious.

It won't work with the VPN client in Windows. You'll need to install wireguard.

@vidarlo, thank you. In this case your particular recommendation (wireguard) contradicts my initial requirements in the question. My goal is to use the built-in Windows VPN client to avoid installing third-party software.
